# Encoding issue Android / REST /JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, encoding

i´m trying to solve encoding issue for response (json) from simple rest service in my app for about one day now, no more ideas..

when i open response in restclient, getting correct result:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 270
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 09:26:39 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

response:

```
{"reqStatus": 1,
"articles": [
{
  "articleId": "1",
  "articleName": "Schüssel 18cm",
  "articlePrice": "34.50",
  "articleDate": "2016-03-15 17:34:00",
  "userZip": "76879",
  "userCity": "Ottersheim",
  "articleImages": [ ...
```

for inputstream getting that:

```
{"reqStatus":1,"articles":[{"articleId":"1","articleName":"Sch\u00fcssel 18cm","articlePrice":"34.50","articleDate":"2016-03-15 17:34:00","userZip":"76879","userCity":"Ottersheim","articleImages":[ ...
```

code for request:

```
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(serviceUrl);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        if (headers!=null&&headers.length>0){

            for (int i=0;i < headers.length;i++){

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty(headers[i][0].toString(), headers[i][1].toString());
            }
        }


        urlConnection.connect()


        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);


            return new JSONObject(inputStr);
        }
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong? What does not work?

Comment: You are correctly using InputStreamReader with fixed charset, therefore you should get the correct response if the input is correct. Are you sure that the server sends the data encoded as UTF-8 as it claims to do?